# Raspberry- display reformatted

Tags: css, formatting, raspberry-pi, display

I am new to using raspberry pi. I am working on the frontend of a project, which looks fine when viewed from my laptop. However, the text gets reformatted, when I run the code on the raspberry pi. Below are the screenshots of the 2 displays.

Note: both the displays are run on the same browser, chromium, and are full screen. I am not sure why is there a difference in how the text is formatted. 1st image is of the raspberry pi display, next of the mac display.

[image: Raspberry pi display]

[image: mac display]

Answer (score 1):

Worked fine after removing some padding. But, still odd that I had to do that.